# Node.js, discord.js & MySQL - ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'NAME' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

Just started coding a discord bot 2 days ago and I'm now stuck here.
The error I get: `ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'mariobot.522488285910663201' doesn't exist`

Part of code that has to do with this:

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM ??`, [targetUserId], (err, result, fields) => {
  if (err) {
    con.query(
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?? (userName varchar(255),positiveVouches int(10),negativeVouches int(10),totalVouches int(10),createdAt timestamp)`,
      [targetUserId],
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`Table for ${userName} successfully created.`);
      }
    );

    message.react("✅");
    message.reply(`you successfully registered.`);

    var sql = mysql.format(
      "INSERT INTO ?? SET ? = ?, positiveVouches = 0,negativeVouches = 0,totalVouches = 0,createdAt = ?",
      [targetUserId, "userName", userName, dformat]
    );
    con.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
      console.log(sql);
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });
    console.log(`Row for ${userName} successfully added.`);
  } else {
    console.log(
      `${userName} tried to register again but a table already` + ` exists`.red
    );
    message.react("❎");
    message.reply(`you are already registered.`);
  }
});
```

The table exists in the database so I don't know what really causes it.
[DATABASE TABLE IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiQEF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that while the `CREATE TABLE` statement is run, the following code is not done inside its callback. This means that while the statement is running, the code after it (`message.react()` etc.) is ran before the `CREATE TABLE` statement finishes. The same issue exists with the later `con.query`.

To fix this, move your code inside the callback which runs *after* the `CREATE TABLE` is finished:

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM ??`, [targetUserId], (err, result, fields) => {
  if (err) {
    con.query(
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?? (userName varchar(255),positiveVouches int(10),negativeVouches int(10),totalVouches int(10),createdAt timestamp)`,
      [targetUserId],
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`Table for ${userName} successfully created.`);

        message.react("✅");
        message.reply(`you successfully registered.`);

        var sql = mysql.format(
          "INSERT INTO ?? SET ? = ?, positiveVouches = 0,negativeVouches = 0,totalVouches = 0,createdAt = ?",
          [targetUserId, "userName", userName, dformat]
        );
        con.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
          console.log(sql);
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }

          console.log(`Row for ${userName} successfully added.`);
        });
      }
    );
  } else {
    console.log(
      `${userName} tried to register again but a table already` + ` exists`.red
    );
    message.react("❎");
    message.reply(`you are already registered.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't output any errors in the terminal but I still see no rows in the database for some reason.
Console: https://i.imgur.com/QQ008nP.png
DB: https://i.imgur.com/fo9DMnx.png

When I manually execute the query in the phpAdmin console it says invalid syntax.

Comment: @mariokamani Does it work if you change the table name to `mariobot.\`522488285910663201\`` in the query ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it does. https://imgur.com/a/n0Sw55I

Comment: And you're certain that you've connected to the same database host and chosen the same database? What if you pass `debug: true` to createConnection to see the raw queries being sent, and run those in the same order in the database admin tool?

Comment: Changed the query from `INSERT INTO ?? SET ? = ?` to `INSERT INTO ?? SET userName = ?` and this seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Great! Yeah, you probably need to use ?? with identifiers like table names.